# Generate truly random numbers in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**NOTE**: I am a beginner and new to Unity and C#.

I am making a game in unity (2d) and I want to make the enemy spawners to always be around the player but in a random position. The problem is that all the spawners all use the same position instead of all using different positions.

Generating random numbers code:

```
float xOffset = Random.Range(0, 50);
float yOffset = Random.Range(0, 50);
```

I've tried some things like changing the seed and creating new `Random` objects (`new Random()`) but it all had the same result as above (they all used the same position)

Comment: Keep in mind that "truly" random numbers are not easy to generate.  Computers that generate truly random numbers must use a physical, random event to seed their RNG.  Something like radioactive decay of an isotope would work.  The System.Random class provides pseudo-random number generation - not true RNG.

Comment: In programming we typically talk about *pseudo random* and *cryptographically secure random*. Only the later is "true random", or at least as true as feasible, but that is complete overkill for a game (unless money is involved). Chances are that you are just using the random class incorrectly.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography  - RandomNumberGenerator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-8.0

Comment: Make sure that when you use the random class you aren't giving it a seed. The same seed results in the same numbers being generated. That's why all your positions are the same each time. The seed is the same each time.

Comment: Please show the whole function which includes the code you provided, and how you apply those `xOffset` and `yOffset`.

Comment: (Assuming you're calling Unity's `Random.Range()`) The code you posted will correctly generate random numbers with only a 1/50 chance of them both being the same. Therefore, the error must be in some other code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a typecast error and Unity is using a different overload of Random.Range() than you intended. eg: `Random.Range(int, int)`

as per https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

> There is an int overload of this function that operates slightly differently, especially regarding the range maximum. See its docs below.

Try changing your code and specify your range values as floats

```cs
float xOffset = Random.Range(0f, 50f);
float yOffset = Random.Range(0f, 50f);
```

Comment: I feel like calling it a "typecast error", whatever that's supposed to be, misses the point. This is user error, one that's hard to miss, but still no fault of Unity or anyone but the developer.

Comment: "there might be a typecast error" was in reference to the code provided and the intention of the author. I was not suggesting a flaw with unity.